# can't retrieve youtube title using yt.title from pytube library

Tags: python, pytube

After running this:

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')
print(yt.title)
```

python version 3.11.3

I receive this error:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jay\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\youtube.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(yt.title)
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jay\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 346, in title
    raise exceptions.PytubeError(
pytube.exceptions.PytubeError: Exception while accessing title of https://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo.
```

I was expecting to receive a title

Comment: since yesterday pytube doesn't work at all **__main__.py", line 161, in streaming_data
    return self.vid_info['streamingData']
KeyError: 'streamingData'** Did YouTube change something?

Comment: tnx, what other options do we have? youtube-dl is also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using yt-dlp plugin.

Answer (score 1):

According to the solution [here](https://Try%20going%20to%20Pytube/innertube.py%20in%20line%2078%20change%20client%20=%20%27ANDRIOD%27%20to%20client%20=%20%27WEB%27)

> Try going to Pytube/innertube.py in line 78 change client = 'ANDRIOD' to client = 'WEB'

for newbies using linux like me: Pytube is hidden somewhere in /home/user/.local/share/...(virtualenvs depending on your's)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Pytube/__main__.py` in line 244 change `client = 'ANDRIOD'` to `client = 'WEB'`

this worked for me.

Comment: Modifying libraries isn't usually a good idea. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Chris no need to worry, it's totally fine. Sometimes there are bugs in modules, so we have to dive in the code to fix it